# reference for ejb jboss and eclipse development

Tags: netbeans, ide, jboss, ejb

is there a reference or book, maybe a tutorial that can get me started with ejb using the technologies that I have mentioned above?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) if you're interested in developing Java EE applications in Eclipse.

If you already know EJB (and if you don't there is quite good [Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158025) book) you know you can develop your EJB's as plain POJO's just with annotations. No need for fancy plugins here.

You would, however, need a plugin to easily deploy your application to the server. In this case, take a look at these JBoss Tools and [this topic](http://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/04/18/how-to-use-jboss-as-7-with-jboss-tools-developer-studio).

Comment: hey thanks man. appreciate the help. you know it is kinda hard grasping the concept of o/r mapping especially the entity relationships but i guess the enterprise javabeans book would help. :D thanks again

Comment: The EJB's are not for entities. They used to be in old times when EJB Entities were present in EJB 2.x specification. Right now EJB serves as a boundary of your application and business logic and the entities are modeled as POJOs with JPA annotations.

Comment: oh geez, i got my definitions mixed up. i better start working on that book you suggested. :D i really appreciate the info, thanks.